# Catching newlines in textbox in XUL

Tags: javascript, firefox, textbox, firefox-addon, xul

**Question:** how can I grab the newlines in a string entered into a textbox created as described below?

**Motivation:** I am trying to make a couple really simple modifications to a FireFox extension (Zotero) to make it easier for me to use.  This extension allows you to enter tags for an item by typing them into a textbox and hitting enter.  I would like to be able to enter a bunch of tags at once by pasting them into the textbox as a string with newline as the delimiter between tags.  newline was chosen because other characters are viable choices for use in the tag itself.

**Problem:** when I paste a string into the entry textbox right now, it strips out all of the newlines and replaces them with single spaces.  I can't find anywhere in the extension code where this happens, so I think it is a property of the textbox itself.  I am trying to look up documentation for this textbox to see if there are some properties I can play with so that I can catch the newlines, but I am not very familiar with JavaScript and HTML and am having trouble finding anything.  I'd like to find the least invasive solution possible (one that doesn't change the way the textbox currently works for typing in new entries and hitting enter) so that this modification could be adopted into the core version of the extension.

**Resources:** so far the only thing I have found online discussing a similar issue is [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374493/allow-users-to-insert-a-tab-into-a-textbox-but-not-newlines) about allowing tab in a textbox but not newline.  I am not sure if this is an HTML issue (is there a property that could be set to allow the newlines to be retained?) or a JavaScript one (do I need to rewrite the code quoted below?).  I have been trying to look at documentation for both but have not found anything so far (most HTML tutorials discuss textarea rather than textbox).

**Code:** here is the code that creates the textbox object (or is it a method or a form?) I am dealing with:

```
        <method name="showEditor">
            <parameter name="elem"/>
            <body>
            <![CDATA[
                // Blur any active fields
                /*
                if (this._dynamicFields) {
                    this._dynamicFields.focus();
                }
                */

                Zotero.debug('Showing editor');

                var fieldName = 'tag';
                var tabindex = elem.getAttribute('ztabindex');

                var tagID = elem.parentNode.getAttribute('id').split('-')[1];
                var value = tagID ? Zotero.Tags.getName(tagID) : '';
                var itemID = Zotero.getAncestorByTagName(elem, 'tagsbox').item.id;

                var t = document.createElement("textbox");
                t.setAttribute('value', value);
                t.setAttribute('fieldname', fieldName);
                t.setAttribute('ztabindex', tabindex);
                t.setAttribute('flex', '1');

                // Add auto-complete
                t.setAttribute('type', 'autocomplete');
                t.setAttribute('autocompletesearch', 'zotero');
                var suffix = itemID ? itemID : '';
                t.setAttribute('autocompletesearchparam', fieldName + '/' + suffix);

                var box = elem.parentNode;
                box.replaceChild(t, elem);

                // Prevent error when clicking between a changed field
                // and another -- there's probably a better way
                if (!t.select) {
                    return;
                }

                t.select();

                t.addEventListener('blur', function () {
                    document.getBindingParent(this).blurHandler(this);
                }, false);
                t.setAttribute('onkeypress', "return document.getBindingParent(this).handleKeyPress(event)");

                this._tabDirection = false;
                this._lastTabIndex = tabindex;

                return t;
            ]]>
            </body>
        </method>
```

Comment: Newline in JavaScript (as well as a bunch of other programming languages) is `\r\n` (see here: http://jsfiddle.net/QmMPN/). Try searching `\r\n` in the code of the extension. The case could be also that newlines in HTML code are displayed as whitespaces in the browser, unless you put `<br>` tags in the HTML (or have HTML elements that display as blocks rather than inline). I don't see anything newline-related in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is actually about XUL, not HTML.  The documentation for the textbox object can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/textbox

The property that needs to be set is newlines.  By setting this to 'pasteintact' the newlines can be retained.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with firefox extensions, but regular textboxes do not strip newlines.

There is something else going on there. Probably something for creating tags that is validating characters.

You will need to read the source more closely to find where it's happening, but it's not due to the textbox (unless extensions have something unusual).

Comment: I have looked at the code for adding tags.  There is a method called addTag().  I added an alert(tagString) right at the beginning of this method to show the tag string.  The newline is already stripped at this point.  Does document.createElement("textbox") in the quoted code above create a standard HTML textbox?  I feel like finding more information about this object might help me discover where the newlines are getting stripped.  There is a function defined elsewhere in the extension that strips newlines from text, but I don't see it called anywhere in relation to tags.

Comment: Put an alert on that function and see if it really doesn't get called.

Comment: I tried and it didn't pop up, so I guess it does not use that function at least.

Comment: Two options: Contact the author of the addon, or strip everything out and do a very simple addon, just to test the textarea, then start adding things back in slowly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried option one before my original post but still haven't heard back.  Option two is tricky because the addon is pretty complex so it is hard to rip everything out but the part I need without knowing the answer to my question already, but I will keep playing with it.  I tried printing out the properties of the textbox element -- it has a ton.  It will take me a while to figure out what they are all for, but I guess I will try going over them next.